# Normalizing data to certain range of values

Tags: python, normalize

I am a new in Python, is there any function that can do normalizing a data?

For example, I have set of list in range `0 - 1` example : `[0.92323, 0.7232322, 0,93832, 0.4344433]`

I want to normalize those all values to range `0.25 - 0.50`

Thank you,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could do sth along the following lines:

```
>>> l = [0.92323, 0.7232322, 0.93832, 0.4344433]
>>> lower, upper = 0.25, 0.5
>>> l_norm = [lower + (upper - lower) * x for x in l]
>>> l_norm
[0.4808075, 0.43080805, 0.48458, 0.35861082499999997]
```

Comment: it's cool, can I do in dataframe? I tried but got an error when I use it on apply.

Comment: What about the range 0,1 ?

Comment: Cool, but this is work only for values between 0 and 1 and not outside of them. But the @user46543 asked for that so is fine for him, but in my case the [Adirio answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48109733/10234009) is a general one and is work and out side of 0 and 1.

Answer (score 15):

The following function considers the generic case:

```
def normalize(values, bounds):
    return [bounds['desired']['lower'] + (x - bounds['actual']['lower']) * (bounds['desired']['upper'] - bounds['desired']['lower']) / (bounds['actual']['upper'] - bounds['actual']['lower']) for x in values]
```

Use:

```
normalize(
    [0.92323, 0.7232322, 0.93832, 0.4344433],
    {'actual': {'lower': 0, 'upper': 1}, 'desired': {'lower': 0.25, 'upper': 0.5}}
) # [0.4808075, 0.43080805, 0.48458, 0.35861082499999997]

normalize(
    [5, 7.5, 10, 12.5, 15],
    {'actual':{'lower':5,'upper':15},'desired':{'lower':1,'upper':2}}
) # [1.0, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 2.0]
```

I chose a two-level dict as the argument but you could give it in multiple ways, for example in two separate tuples, one for the actual bounds and the other for the desired, being the first element the lower bound and the second the upper:

```
def normalize(values, actual_bounds, desired_bounds):
    return [desired_bounds[0] + (x - actual_bounds[0]) * (desired_bounds[1] - desired_bounds[0]) / (actual_bounds[1] - actual_bounds[0]) for x in values]
```

Use:

```
   normalize(
    [0.92323, 0.7232322, 0.93832, 0.4344433],
    (0,1),
    (0.25,0.5)
) # [0.4808075, 0.43080805, 0.48458, 0.35861082499999997]

normalize(
    [5, 7.5, 10, 12.5, 15],
    (5,15),
    (1,2)
) # [1.0, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 2.0]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sklearn.preprocessing` for a lot of types of pre-processing tasks including normalization.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the above answers do not give you the values in the range you are asking. Here I present an alternative function that may be easy to follow and gives you the result in the range you are asking.

```
def normalize(x, newRange=(0, 1)): #x is an array. Default range is between zero and one
    xmin, xmax = np.min(x), np.max(x) #get max and min from input array
    norm = (x - xmin)/(xmax - xmin) # scale between zero and one
    
    if newRange == (0, 1):
        return(norm) # wanted range is the same as norm
    elif newRange != (0, 1):
        return norm * (newRange[1] - newRange[0]) + newRange[0] #scale to a different range.    
    #add other conditions here. For example, an error message
```

Aplying our new function to your problem

```
x = np.array([0.92323, 0.7232322, 0.93832, 0.4344433]) #your input vector must be an array
normalize(x, newRange=(0.25, 0.5)) #set your range as a python tuple
#array([0.49251305, 0.39328352, 0.5       , 0.25      ]) 
#note that the new values have a maximum value of 0.5 (the third entry) and minimum of 0.25 (the last value).
```