# Data frame normalization center = 0 solution (-1, 1)?

Tags: python, pandas, normalization

I have multiple variables in my data frame with negative and positive values. Thus I'd like to normalize/scale the variables between -1, 1. I didnt find a working solution. Any suggestions? Thanks a lot!

I scaled other variables with the sklearn MinMaxScaler 0, 1. Didn't find an additional -1, 1 solution there.

Comment: does this help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48109228/normalizing-data-to-certain-range-of-values

Comment: and this may also be relevant : https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/178626/how-to-normalize-data-between-1-and-1

Answer (score 0):

Min max scaler uses a mathematical formula that converts values between 0,1 not -1,1

if you want values between -1,1 try `sklean's` `StandardScaler`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes, but I used minmaxscaler only for positive columns, where I wanted to scale 0, 1. Thank you, ill try the standardschaler for +/- columns!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a mathematical answer to your question:

`result = (row - min_col) * (high - low) / (max_col - min_col) + low`

Where:

- **row** = the number to be transformed in the row
- **min_col** = the minimum value in the column
- **max_col** = the maximum value in the column
- **low** = the minimum value of the transformed results (-1)
- **high** = the maximum value of the transformed results (+1)

---

**Here is the code:**

```py
import random
import pandas as pd

# Generate some random numbers (-300 to 300) and place into a dataframe (df)
res = [random.randint(-300,300) for i in range(100)]
df = pd.DataFrame({"data":res})


# Function to transform the rows of a column (between -1 and 1)
def transform(row, min_col, max_col, low = -1, high=1):
    result = (row - min_col) * (high - low) / (max_col - min_col) + low;
    return result


# Identify the minimum and the maximum of the column in question
column_min = min(df['data'])
column_max = max(df['data'])

# Generate a new column with the transformed values
df['transformed'] = df['data'].apply(transform, min_col = column_min, max_col=column_max)

# Print the dataframe
print(df)
```

**df OUTPUT:**

[image]

Comment: okay, thank you for the mathematical solution, Ill check that out